# Steam crashes after updating

Tags: steam

So I'm new to ubuntu and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. Every time I try to load steam, it will update then close. If I try running it through the terminal this happens:

```
benjy@Bens-UL:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
/home/benjy/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
[2021-02-08 21:34:06] Startup - updater built Feb  8 2021 05:16:36
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1612763122)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  51
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  52
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2021-02-08 21:34:06] Loading cached metrics from disk (/home/benjy/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_metrics.bin)
[2021-02-08 21:34:06] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2021-02-08 21:34:06] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2021-02-08 21:34:06] 1. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 0, source = 'baked in'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1612763122)
[2021-02-08 21:34:06] Checking for update on startup
[2021-02-08 21:34:06] Checking for available updates...
[2021-02-08 21:34:06] Downloading manifest: http://media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1612763122)
[2021-02-08 21:34:06] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1612763122, installed version 1612763122, downloaded version 0
[2021-02-08 21:34:06] Nothing to do
[2021-02-08 21:34:06] Verifying installation...
[2021-02-08 21:34:06] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2021-02-08 21:34:07] Verification complete
Loaded SDL version 2.0.15-6355349
Gtk-Message: 21:34:07.151: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 21:34:07.176: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(steam:8287): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:34:07.179: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gtk-2.0/main.rc:775: error: unexpected identifier 'direction', expected character '}'

(steam:8287): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:34:07.180: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gtk-2.0/hacks.rc:28: error: invalid string constant "normal_entry", expected valid string constant
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
Major opcode of failed request:  152
Serial number of failed request:  52
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  152
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  51
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  152
Serial number of failed request:  53
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
assert_20210208213406_1.dmp[8334]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20210208213406_1.dmp
/home/benjy/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 759:  8287 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
benjy@Bens-UL:~$ assert_20210208213406_1.dmp[8334]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20210208213406_1.dmp[8334]: response: CrashID=bp-872f703e-9e2d-4903-b006-788ac2210208
assert_20210208213406_1.dmp[8334]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20210208213406_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-872f703e-9e2d-4903-b006-788ac2210208''
```

I have no idea how to fix this, please help!

Comment: What video card and driver are you using?